# Post JSON to update Rails resource through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, net-http

**The Goal:**
Send a POST request to an API endpoint, and modify that resource using Rails.  I've been at this error for almost 6 hours today with no luck; can someone please point me in the right direction? All relevant details included below:

**routes.rb** for the relevant route:
`post '/complete_transportation_request' => 'api/transportation/complete#complete_request'`

**api/transportation/complete_controller.rb** (the method that handles this request:

```
def complete_request
 @ride = Transportation.find(params["transportation"]["id"])
 @ride.update(transportation_params)
end
```

The file from which I'm calling the attempted POST request:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
....  
def test_post_request(result)
  params = {"transportation"=>{"id"=>6, "state"=>"Complete"}}
  url = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/complete_transportation_request")
  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)

  puts resp.inspect
  puts data.inspect
  puts resp.body
  puts params
end
```

**error being thrown:**

## ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /complete_transportation_request

> Couldn't find Transportation with 'id'=id

### app/controllers/api/transportation/complete_controller.rb, line 10

````
``` ruby
5       @rides = ::Transportation.where(state: "Complete")
6     end
7   
8   
9     def complete_request
>  10       @ride = Transportation.find(params["transportation"]["id"])
11       @ride.update(transportation_params)
12     end
13   
14     private
15   
```
````

**Edit 1: `params` at the point of failure:**

```
[2] pry(#<Api::Transportation::CompleteController>)> params
=> nil
```

**Edit 2: Full `pry` output at point of failure:**

```
Started POST "/complete_transportation_request" for ::1 at 2015-08-23 19:58:49 -0700
Processing by Api::Transportation::CompleteController#complete_request as */*
Parameters: {"transportation"=>"{\"id\"=>\"6\", \"state\"=>\"Complete\"}"}
"Id = id"

From: .... line 11 Api::Transportation::CompleteController#complete_request:

 9: def complete_request
10:     p "Id = #{params["transportation"]["id"]}"
11:     binding.pry
12:     params = JSON.parse(params)
13:     @ride = Transportation.find(params["transportation"]["id"])
14:   @ride.update(transportation_params)
15: end

[1] pry(#<Api::Transportation::CompleteController>)> params
=> nil
```

**Edit 3: What am I missing? Parameters seem to be right there in the log for the request!**

```
Started POST "/complete_transportation_request" for ::1 at 2015-08-23 21:37:18 -0700
Processing by Api::Transportation::CompleteController#complete_request as */*
Parameters: {"id"=>"7", "state"=>"Complete"}

From: ...../app/controllers/api/transportation/complete_controller.rb @ line 11 Api::Transportation::CompleteController#complete_request:

10: def complete_request
=> 11:  binding.pry
12:     params = JSON.parse(params)
13:     @ride = Transportation.find(params["transportation"]["id"])
14:   @ride.update(transportation_params)
15: end

[1] pry(#<Api::Transportation::CompleteController>)> params
=> nil
```

Comment: Try a  `p params` in `complete_request` and see what is coming in.

Comment: could you please add this line just before your line 10:  `p "Id = #{params["transportation"]["id"]}"` and let us know what comes up?

Comment: `params` came up nil - I will update my question with that info.. so params are nil at the point of failure, it must be an issue with the POST itself, right?

Comment: very likely... do you mind adding to your question the rails log file for the POST event?

Comment: Yes, I've just added that to the question

Answer (score 0):

Problem in "edit 2": ensure both `content-type` and `accepts` headers in the request contain `application/json`, and not for example `text/json`, or that you didn't do something strange like plug in a json raw string inside a "transportation" text field in a basic HTTP form. If you still have problems, add `.json` at the end at it'll probably work

problem in "edit 3", try do do find for `params['id']` and not `params['transportation']['id']`.

Also, you're kind of mixing things together which don't mix well, post_form sends a form, like on a HTML page, forms in Rails are typically nested - they have a root node like 'transportation', XMLs are nested too, JSON's are NOT nested unless you plug in extra middleware to force it so,

use `curl` to test your controller:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -k -i -d '{"id": "2874"}' http://localhost:3000/complete_transportation_request.json
```

and use `find params['id']` to fetch the record